# has reference to / is in reference to

Tags: grammar

I heard this sentence in a movie:

> "Who is that "you" in reference to exactly?"

and since I don't usually limit myself by a fixed number of sentence structures, I used it in this way:

> "Who that "you" has reference to exactly?"

I Wonder if my own sentence is correct/well-understood as well? (I feel the second one is only a bit more formal sounding, but not wrong.)

Comment: In a standard question the subject must invert with an auxiliary verb.

Comment: @StoneyB Can you give an example?

Comment: Who **does that "you"** have reference to exactly?

Comment: So you mean it would be more grammatical if I said "Who has that "you" reference to exactly?"

Comment: *HAVE* is wonky. Until about a century or so ago it was treated (like *BE*) as an auxiliary in all contexts and could invert without *do* support even when employed as a lexical verb, as here. That use lingers in formal registers; but it has mostly disappeared from US spoken Englishes, and seems to have declined in British spoken Englishes too. I recommend that you follow contemporary usage and employ *do* support with lexical *HAVE*.